# Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterValue: The input isn't valid. Input can't contain control characters. │

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Failing to # terraform apply  (on rds creation tf)

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 5
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = file("../rds_pass.txt")
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = "true"
}
```

Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterValue: The input isn't valid. Input can't contain control characters. status code: 400, request id: e4632bae-72fc-4912-9514-d7a8c37550e5,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across the same problem.
I just removed `parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"` from `aws_db_instance`.
Hope it will helpful for others too...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are following the Zeal Voras Lectures, here is what I did to fix this issue.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  db_name              = "mydb"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "${file("../../../rds_pass.txt")}"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
}
```

Furthermore, make sure that RDS password is in small letters, capital letters are not allowed.

Wrong Example: MySuperPassword

Correct Example: mysuperpassword

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i have some problem like this too :

```
aws_db_instance.default: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating RDS DB Instance (terraform-20221124001123411100000001): InvalidParameterValue: The input isn't valid. Input can't contain control characters.
│   status code: 400, request id: 437bc1c1-92bc-43d8-8bc6-721c64ae513a
│
│   with aws_db_instance.default,
│   on ksm_rds_password.tf line 8, in resource "aws_db_instance" "default":
│    8: resource "aws_db_instance" "default"{
```

here my terraform code

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default"{
  allocated_storage           = 20
  max_allocated_storage       = 50
storage_type                = var.storagetype["gp2"]
  engine                      = var.engine["mysql"]
  engine_version              = var.engineversion["mysql8031"]
  instance_class              = var.dbinstancetype["dbmicro"]
  db_name                     = var.custom["dbnm"]
  username                    = data.aws_kms_secrets.rds-secret.plaintext["username"]
  password                    = data.aws_kms_secrets.rds-secret.plaintext["master_password"]
  #parameter_group_name        = var.parameternoption["stagdevparameter"]
  db_subnet_group_name        = var.subnet["privdba"]
  vpc_security_group_ids      = aws_security_group.sg-rds-stag-ups[*].id
  allow_major_version_upgrade = true
  auto_minor_version_upgrade  = true
  backup_retention_period     = 35
  backup_window               = "22:00-23:00"
  maintenance_window          = "Sat:00:00-Sat:03:00"
  multi_az                    = true
  skip_final_snapshot         = true
  
  tags = {
    usage = "staging"
    customer = "dev"

 }
```

here version terraform

```
terraform version                                                                                                                                                                                  1 ↵  10426  07:18:28
Terraform v1.3.5
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.40.0
```

```
terraform validate                                                                                                                                                                                   ✔  10427  07:18:30
Success! The configuration is valid.
 # aws_db_instance.default will be created
  + resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
      + address                               = (known after apply)
      + allocated_storage                     = 20
      + allow_major_version_upgrade           = true
      + apply_immediately                     = (known after apply)
      + arn                                   = (known after apply)
      + auto_minor_version_upgrade            = true
      + availability_zone                     = (known after apply)
      + backup_retention_period               = 35
      + backup_window                         = "22:00-23:00"
      + ca_cert_identifier                    = (known after apply)
      + character_set_name                    = (known after apply)
      + copy_tags_to_snapshot                 = false
      + db_name                               = "stag-dev"
      + db_subnet_group_name                  = "subnet-04257ecd16c4acbf2"
      + delete_automated_backups              = true
      + endpoint                              = (known after apply)
      + engine                                = "mysql"
      + engine_version                        = "8.0.31"
      + engine_version_actual                 = (known after apply)
      + hosted_zone_id                        = (known after apply)
      + id                                    = (known after apply)
      + identifier                            = (known after apply)
      + identifier_prefix                     = (known after apply)
      + instance_class                        = "db.t3.micro"
      + kms_key_id                            = (known after apply)
      + latest_restorable_time                = (known after apply)
      + license_model                         = (known after apply)
      + maintenance_window                    = "sat:00:00-sat:03:00"
      + max_allocated_storage                 = 50
      + monitoring_interval                   = 0
      + monitoring_role_arn                   = (known after apply)
      + multi_az                              = false
      + name                                  = (known after apply)
      + nchar_character_set_name              = (known after apply)
      + network_type                          = (known after apply)
      + option_group_name                     = (known after apply)
      + password                              = (sensitive value)
      + performance_insights_enabled          = false
      + performance_insights_kms_key_id       = (known after apply)
      + performance_insights_retention_period = (known after apply)
      + port                                  = (known after apply)
      + publicly_accessible                   = false
      + replica_mode                          = (known after apply)
      + replicas                              = (known after apply)
      + resource_id                           = (known after apply)
      + skip_final_snapshot                   = true
      + snapshot_identifier                   = (known after apply)
      + status                                = (known after apply)
      + storage_type                          = "gp2"
      + tags                                  = {
          + "user" = "dev"
          + "usage"    = "staging"
        }
      + tags_all                              = {
          + "user" = "dev"
          + "usage"    = "staging"
        }
      + timezone                              = (known after apply)
      + username                              = ""
      + vpc_security_group_ids                = [
          + "sg-xxx",
        ]
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

need advance in here ... many thanks before and after

Answer (score 0):

found root problem was :

can't load character - since i remove all  variable containe -.
also can't working with payload data from aws_kms_secrets so i can't  encrypted password and username using  payload aws_kms_secrets